# How to write junit test case for below class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am learning JUnit with Mockito. I am getting any idea on how to start and how to write unit tests for the below class. It would be pleasure if someone would help me in writing them:

```
@Service
public class GetDataFromHistDataImpl implements GetDataFromHistData{    

  @Override
  public File downloadData(String formUrl) {
    String tk = null;
    String date= null;
    String datemonth= null;
    String platform= null;
    String timeframe= null;
    String fxpair= null;

    WebClient webClient=new WebClient();

    try 
    {
        HtmlPage page1=webClient.getPage(formUrl);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false); 
        HtmlForm form=page1.getFormByName("file_down");
        tk=form.getInputByName("tk").getAttribute("value");
        date=form.getInputByName("date").getAttribute("value");
        datemonth=form.getInputByName("datemonth").getAttribute("value");
        platform=form.getInputByName("platform").getAttribute("value");
        timeframe=form.getInputByName("timeframe").getAttribute("value");;
        fxpair=form.getInputByName("fxpair").getAttribute("value"); 
        System.out.println("fx"+fxpair);
        webClient.close();

    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();

    WebTarget target = client.target("http://www.histdata.com/get.php");

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedStringMap();
    map.add("tk", tk);
    map.add("date", date);
    map.add("datemonth", datemonth);
    map.add("platform", platform);
    map.add("timeframe", timeframe);
    map.add("fxpair", fxpair);

    InputStream responseStream = target.request().header("Referer", "http://www.histdata.com/")
            .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "tar, deflate")
            .post(Entity.form(map), InputStream.class);

        File file = new File("data.tar");

        OutputStream fos;
        try 
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = responseStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {

                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
        }       
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

        return file;
}

@Override
public File unZipData(File zipFile) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "/Users/venkateswara/Downloads/Sindhu/histdata";
    File returnFileName=null;
     try{

        File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        if(ze==null)
        {
            System.out.println("ZipFile is empty or corrupted");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while(ze!=null){

           String fileName = ze.getName();
           File newFile = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER + File.separator + fileName);
           if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(newFile.getName()).contains("csv"))
           {
               returnFileName=newFile.getAbsoluteFile();
           }

            //create all non exists folders
            //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();   
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }   
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();    
    }
     catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  return returnFileName;    

}

private InsertHistDao insertHistDao;

@Autowired
public void setInsertHistIntoDb(InsertHistDao insertHistDao) {
    this.insertHistDao = insertHistDao;
}


@Override
public void getDataFromCsv(File unZipFile,String sym) {
    String[] csvLine=null;
    try 
    {
        CSVReader csvReader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(unZipFile));
        while((csvLine=csvReader.readNext())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("data :"+Arrays.toString(csvLine));
            insertHistDao.insertHistIntoDb(csvLine,sym);
            rowsInserted++;
            System.out.println("Rows inserted:"+rowsInserted);
        }
        csvReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
```

This is the class for which I want to do unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to listen to these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). Seriously; if you want to do unit testing, then you should step back and understand what that **really means**.

In your case, your code can't be tested easily. That **starts** with: your  method does create the webClient object it is working with using **new**. That means: your testing code has **no** control over that object. Without control, testing is impossible!

Instead, you could be using dependency injection. That means: you create a way so that your testing code can give a **mocked** webClient object to your code under test. And then you can simply describe: I expect this call to happen on my mock; and then, that value should be returned.

But of course, that is just the **first** object in your method. Your other problem is that you are doing **way too many** things within that one method. Instead, you have to break apart into many smaller things. Then you create more classes/objects that take part of the different functionalities. And you test of them on their own.

So, long story short:

1. You really have to step back to understand that code that profits from unit-testing ... must be written in a very different manner!
2. In order to get the most out of unit testing; you not only have to learn about "unit testing practices" and frameworks, but "how to create clean code" and [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) OO designs.

Comment: @GostCat Thanks for your feedback on my code. Thats very helpful.       But I am having few doubts.                                                                           1. From the first point in your feedback you specified that I am using new keyword and its a bad practice. Is it that we should not at all use 'new' keyword for better control over code??  So if what to create a new File object for ex, should we create it using dependency injection??                   2. Can you please shed some light on 'breaking apart into smaller things' that you specified in 2nd point with example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommended you to try write JUnit tests for easier blocks of code. Just easy return value and so on. Then learn how to create mocks and why.
Good point is, that you could write clean and easy-understand code. Than you can write JUnit tests easier.

I allways follow rule "AAA" (Arrange, Act, Assert). Arrange - set up mocks, variables and so on. Act - there you can teach your mocks what they should do. Assert - this block is for assert your expect value with actual.

Comment: Thanks @Richard H. for your suggestion.